# download function in separate thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking

in my android application there gonna be some files to download once in a while.
so I've written a download function like this:

```
public static void download(Context context, String url, String path) {
   URLConnection conection = new URL(url).openConnection();
   conection.connect();
   InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
   OutputStream os = context.openFileOutput(path, 0);
   pipe(is, os);   // write from inputstream to outputstream
   os.close();
}
```

I can't decide to put this function in a separate thread or not?
when I put it in a separate thread then if I want to downalod 10 files with a for-loop then all of them begin downloading in 10 simultaneously separate threads which is not good!
when I don't put in a separate thread then main thread must wait till the downloading finishes which is not good too!

what's the solution?

Comment: thread + fixed size pool executor

Answer (score 0):

Solution is not to put this function into thread, but call the function from thread when you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both to have files being downloaded in the background and have them download one at a time, use ThreadPoolExecutor and submit Runnables to it:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html